# Como obter tamanho de um arquivo em um servidor externo?

Tags: php, javascript

Galera queria saber se teria como pegar o tamanho de um arquivo que esta hospedado em um servidor externo por exemplo: um audio no servidor do google www.google.com/audio.mp3  teria como eu pegar o filesize deste arquivo mesmo n estando em meu servidor com php ou javascript ?

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa ter a extensão cURL , com o qual você pode fazer uma solicitação HTTP HEAD para o servidor remoto. A resposta vai deixar você saber como grande é o arquivo.

Exemplo:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); //specify the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$head = curl_exec($ch);

$size = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);

if(<limit the $size>){
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```